# What is the best way to make the output of one stream the input to another

Tags: .net, iostream

I'm wondering if there is a better/inbuilt way, other than using a byte buffer and looping, to read from one stream and write it to another (in .NET). Generally this is done to apply a transform to a stream and move it on.

In this instance, what I am loading a file, putting it through a deflate stream and writing it out to a file (Error handling removed for simplicity):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];
using (FileStream fsin = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (FileStream fsout = new FileStream(zipfilename, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        using (DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(fsout, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            int read = 0;
            do
            {
                read = fsin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ds.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            while (read > 0);
        }
    }
}
buffer = null;
```

**Edit:**

.NET 4.0 now has a Stream.CopyTo function, Hallelujah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not really a better way than that, though I tend to put the looping part into a `CopyTo` extension method, e.g.

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination)
{
    var buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int bytesInBuffer;
    while ((bytesInBuffer = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesInBuffer);
    }
}
```

Which you could then call as:

```
fsin.CopyTo(ds);
```

Comment: Yes, I would do this if we were on 3.5. Generally we put it in a static method library.

Comment: Indeed, it used to be called StreamCopier.Copy before 3.5 :-)

Comment: Note that it's fine if you're using .NET 2.0, so long as you're using C# 3. You can still use extension methods with a little bit of trickery. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4.0 now has a [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.STREAM.COPYTO%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) function

Answer (score 1):

Now that I think about it, I haven't ever seen any built-in support for piping the results of an input stream directly into an output stream as you're describing. [This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163290.aspx) has some code for a "StreamPipeline" class that does the sort of thing you're describing.