# How do I take the output of one program and use it as the input of another?

Tags: python, ruby, io

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316007/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-the-output-of-one-stream-the-input-to-another) and it wasn't much help.

I have a Ruby program that puts a question to the cmd line and I would like to write a Python program that can return an answer.  Does anyone know of any links or in general how I might go about doing this?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** 
Thanks to the guys that mentioned *piping*.  I haven't used it too much and was glad it was brought up since it forced me too look in to it more.

Comment: You could just use one language but if you are stuck w/o Ruby knowledge, why not...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ruby', 'ruby_program.rb'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ruby_question = p.stdout.readline()
answer = calculate_answer(ruby_question)
p.stdin.write(answer)
print p.communicate()[0]  # prints further info ruby may show.
```

The last 2 lines could be made into one:

```
print p.communicate(answer)[0]
```

Comment: This is good if you want the python program to "be in control".

Comment: @zacherates: which is what you generally want, not? I am sure there is a way to do the same from the ruby side.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on unix / linux you can use piping:

```
question.rb | answer.py
```

Then the output of question.rb becomes the input of answer.py

I've not tried it recently, but I have a feeling the same syntax might work on Windows as well.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think the OP asked for the second program to return and answer *to the ruby program*. I guess it depends on how you interpret "return".

Answer (score 3):

Pexpect

http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect

> Pexpect is a pure Python expect-like
>   module. Pexpect makes Python a better
>   tool for controlling other
>   applications.
>
> Pexpect is a pure Python module for
>   spawning child applications;
>   controlling them; and responding to
>   expected patterns in their output.
>   Pexpect works like Don Libes' Expect.
>   Pexpect allows your script to spawn a
>   child application and control it as if
>   a human were typing commands.

Answer (score 3):

First of all check this out: 
[Unix piping][1]

It works on windows or unix but it's slighly dufferent, first the programs:

question.rb:

```
puts "This is the question"
```

answer.rb:

```
question = gets
#calculate answer
puts "This is the answer"
```

Then the command line:

In unix:

```
question.rb | answer.rb
```

In windows:

```
ruby question.rb | ruby answer.rb
```

Output:

```
This is the question
This is the answer
```

Comment: -1: using pipe means data goes a single way. He specifically asked to return data

Comment: No it doesn't, what I understand is that he needs to get the question from another process, and this is the way it's done since the 70's, your answer is more controlled but almost equivalent to this one. I improved the examples anyway.

Comment: @krusty.ar: He mentions in question that the python program must somehow *return* the answer to the ruby program. So the -1 stands.

Comment: @nosklo: If you construct pipes using only the pipe `|` character, then the data flows one way.  But you can set up a program to use both input and output pipes -- in fact, that's exactly how your Python answer works under the hood.  You don't need Python for this; the Unix shell has been able to do it since the 70s.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: I don't see your point. I mean, yes, but this answer doesn't do that. It uses the pipe `|` character. So it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @nosklo: The answer specifically mentions the Unix concept of a *pipe*, which is not the same as the `|` character (which, ambiguously, can be commonly called "pipe").  You responded: "using pipe means data goes a single way".  I was merely trying to clarify that, while the specific application of the concept of pipes (using `|`) in the answer doesn't completely cover the OP's question, the concept itself is in fact correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways (off the top of my head) to do this.  The simplest if you're in a Unix environment is to use piping.  Simple example:

```
cat .profile .shrc | more
```

This will send the output of the first command (`cat .profile .shrc`) to the `more` command using the pipe character `|`.

The second way is to call one program from the other in your source code.  I'm don't know how Ruby handles this, but in Python you can run a program and get it's output by using the popen function.  See [this example chapter from Learning Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lpython/chapter/ch09.html), then Ctrl-F for "popen" for some example code.

Comment: -1: using pipe means data goes a single way. He specifically asked to return data

Comment: That's one reason why I gave two possible solutions.